# Question about Rudin 3.10

Tags: analysis

Is compactness necessary here?
[image]

Comment: What made you think it is not necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even closed-ness plus boundedness isn't strong enough, necessarily.

Consider the space $X=(0,1)$ under the metric $d(x,y):=|x-y|,$ and consider the sets $$F_n:=\left(0,\frac1{2n}\right].$$ You should be able to show readily that the sets $F_n$ are each closed in $X,$ bounded under $d,$ and meet the hypotheses of part (b) other than compactness. However, their intersection is empty!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, e.g. the sequence $(0,1/n)$ is nested, with finite diameters $1/n \to 0$, but the intersection is empty.